# Can I run an application using Window Builder on Java in the Linux environment?

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse

I have an application written with Java and eclipse in windows 7. I need to know that can I run it on Linux? If not, what should I do to run it in Linux. It's a windows application built with Window Builder on Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **application is in java** then you can surely run it in linux because java is platform independent.All you need to do is to install java in your linux system

Comment: You mean to install JDK or what?

Comment: @user2959717 yes jdk or jre for linux

Comment: @user2959717 accepting answer is the stackoverflow way of saying thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying, **Write once, run everywhere**, for java. Since Java is  platform independent, you can run on any OS.

Just make sure you have Java in your Linux.

Read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28software_platform%29#Platform).